# Mobile Chrome HTML canvas width limit

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I'm trying to display line on HTML canvas after canvas width change.
On all browsers on PC code works fine and line is visible, but on Chrome on Android 4.1.1 - line is not visible.
Here is this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGs4F/2/

```
$( function()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 439;

    context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(1000, 1000);
    context.stroke(); 
} );
```

If You change canvas width to 438 than also on mobile chrom line is visible:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGs4F/

So, Chrome have a problem or I missed something? It does not matter that the line looks identical in both examples, the thing is that this line IS NOT VISIBLE on mobile Chrom :/

Details of my Chrome:

- Package version: 1453090
- Package version name: 27.0.1453.90
- Device: rk30sdk
- SDK version: 16
- Release: 4.1.1
- Incremental version: eng.root.20121102.171658
- Codename: REL

And I'm sure that my code works fine for previous version of Chrome. After last Chrome update this code not works.

Comment: Did you tried put `context.closePath()` after `context.stroke()`? Some Browsers may require it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue with latest Chrome in Android due to 2D acceleration of canvas (bigger canvas gets automatically accelerated). Fortunately is being looked into:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231082

Comment: Just to add, it doesn't effect every device - I tried this on my N4 and it works fine.